# How to bind csv file to a drop down list?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, csv, drop-down-menu, binding

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio, and coding in ASP.net using C#.

I have a drop down list that I wish to bind to a csv file programmatically. I don't know how to or where to start.

I have binded to an ACCESS database (.mdb) before but don't know how csv would work.
Could someone please guide me.

Comment: what do you need to bind to exactly? what's the content of the CSV ?

Comment: First, you need to read the contents of the csv file into a list or `DataTable`, then bind the `ComboBox` to that object.

Comment: you can also use SQL driver for CSV

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Well the excel file has over 100 records so I save it in a csv file. The name of each column in the excel file needs to be displayed in the drop down list. SO essentially there is one read the csv file and two pull all the names of the columns to display in the drop down list

Comment: I am open to using the excel file, if csv is harder to bind and do any more task further on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems you'll have to read it, parse it, and bind it.

Now, the easiest in my opinion would be to use linq to build a custom collection of objects to which you can then bind depending on what you need.

Let's assume your CSV has `name,age` to make it simple.  First, read all lines into a collection (using your preferred method), let's assume it's `InputLines`.

Use linq to get a nice object collection:

```
var my_objects_collection =  
    from line in InputLines
    let parts = line.Split(',')
    select new { name = parts [0], age =  parts [1] };
```

And then, have a read in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/671544/Understanding-SelectedValue-SelectedValuePath-Sele) (and feel free to rate it if it was helpful) to learn how you can bind to a specific value of that collection using the `DisplayMemberPath` , and how you can then use the `SelectedValuePath` to target a specific bit from there.

This should set you on the way to a bright future :)

---

**Edit:**
Linq's your friend ... it lets you treat your collection of objects like an SQL query. Once you get your head around it, it's amazing what you can achieve. Here's a great link to started [101 linq examples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b).

You can even do something like this in order to get the reading of the file into the linq expression:

```
var collection_of_objects = 
    (from line in File.ReadAllLines("your_csv_name.csv").Skip(1)
        let parts = line.Split(',')
        select new
        {
            ID = parts[0],
            First = parts[1],
            Last = parts[2],
            Email = parts[3],
            Gender = parts[4],
            Race = parts[5]
        }
    ).ToList();
```

The line:
`File.ReadAllLines("your_csv_name.csv").Skip(1)`
translates to : read all the lines after skipping the first, which in my case contains the header: `id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,race`, and then for each line it'll create an object with the properties defined after the `new` (note that i'm using the `let` to define a temp variable to hold the result of the `Split`).
In the end , the `ToList()` is used to get a list of "real" objects with properties (without it, you'll get an enumrable, but you won't be able to use the properties like you'll do with a "real" class object).

This allows you to do things like:

```
var some_obj = collection_of_objects.Skip(10).Take(1);
```

in order to take the 11th object, and then you could do things like `some_obj.Gender` or `some_obj.Race` :)

If you'll want to print them all:

```
foreach (var obj in collection_of_objects)
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Some obj fields: {0}, {1}, {2}" , obj.ID, obj.First, obj.Race);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'll try it out keeping in mind that I have no idea what Linq is. So next thing I'm doing is to familiarize myself with linq.

Comment: I really appreciate your help Sir. Now I have a lot of examples to practice and learn from over the weekend. Thanks a lot. I will get back to you on this post about how I went.

Comment: Oy, an oz mate as well ... :) always happy to help. May your team of choice win the ashes as well ...

Comment: Unfortunately, haven't had time to actually watch this series, so no idea what's happening there. Looking forward to the Australian Open next year though. I have one more question, in order for me to read the csv file, do i need to create a separate class that contains the descriptions of all the columns? If so, where do i create it? or can i do all of it in Default.aspx.cs

Comment: Do it wherever you want, however you want . Up to you really

Comment: Sweet as. I used the code that you wrote above, how can I print some fields so i can debug and test for future purposes

Comment: Nah, need help. How do i print/display all the records when i run the code. I have over a 1000 records.

Comment: I got it to work. I used to system.diagnostics.debug.writeline(). I was wondering the way you follow to use linq and connect a csv file, can i pull the meta data and bind it to a drop down list?

Comment: have you read the article at the end of my original reply? once you have your object collection, you can do whatever you want, and in that article, you'll learn some more useful tools and tricks.

Comment: hey do u think you could help me out with this? I want to bind the data using the accepted answer from the link below to a chart. I keep getting an error saying  that argument exception eas unhandled by user code. Series data point do not support values of type <> anonymoustype [system.string,system.string] only values of these types: double, decimal, single, int, long, EVEN string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20209378/need-to-count-duplicates-using-linq-and-bind-it-to-chart/20210015#20210015

Comment: you should probably open another question for this, but seems like you can't bind to an anonymous collection that linq returns. You can create a class with those properties, and instead of `new {properties...' do 'new your_class { properties ...', creating a concrete collection

Comment: I raised a question. This is the link below if you can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234111/unable-to-produce-a-chart-using-linq-in-csharp