# Need to count duplicates using linq and bind it to chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, visual-studio-2012

I am coding in Microsoft Visual Studio in ASP.net using C#. Data is read from a .csv file.

Let say, I have a table that consists of 150 rows by 3 columns. 
The design is as follows: ID, Engine type, Car. The ID columns has a generic ID, engine type column consists of 4 different types of engines and Car column consists of a 1 for yes and 0 for no. This means that yes they have a car and no they don't have a car.

```
var myitems = from a in mylist  
              where (a.Car_ == "1") 
              select a.Engine_Type;
```

This only selects the columns where they "have" a car. I use this and bind it to my chart.

```
Chart1.DataSource = myitems.AsEnumerable().Distinct();
Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Engine Type";
Chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Car";
Chart1.DataBind()
```

My query binds it do the chart perfectly, and the chart has different engine type in the x axis. 
PROBLEM:: This is the problem, lets say there are 137 people with yes so 1 in the car column. and out of the four different types of engines 135 of them have vtec and 2 of them have boxer. I would like to see columns of appropriate values in this case, vtec = 135 and boxer = 2 
So in other words, i need to count how many vtec and boxer's are there in the car column and display it on the same chart. At the moment I use it in a where statement to filter out the zero rows from the table meaning 13 rows don't have a car.

Comment: you can try using [group clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx)

Comment: @Grundy I can't seem to use the where clause in the link that you provided under "Grouping by Bool". I need to view the engine type on the x axis and a total of each engine type on the y axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **GroupBy clause**. Please see below code for the same:

**Design Page:**

```
<asp:Chart runat="server" ID="chart1" Width="500px" Height="500px">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series ChartType="Line" Name="chartSeries" Color="Orange" LabelForeColor="Orange" Font="Tahoma, 11px, style=Bold"
            IsVisibleInLegend="True" BorderWidth="2" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" >
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="carArea" BackColor="Transparent">
            <AxisX Interval="1" TitleForeColor="White" >
                <LabelStyle ForeColor="White" Font="Tahoma, 12px, style=Bold" />
            </AxisX>
            <AxisY>
                <LabelStyle ForeColor="White" Font="Tahoma, 12px, style=Bold" />
            </AxisY>
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
var chartData = mylist.Where(a => a.Car_ == "1").ToList();

foreach (var t in chartData.GroupBy(a => a.Engine_Type))
{
   chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(t.Key, t.Count());
}
```

Comment: your answer makes more sense to me. But it still gives me  "a first chance exception of type 'system.argumentexception' occured in system.web.datavisualisation.dll occured. Any idea what this is?

Comment: in your chart have you defined series ? The error you are facing is may be because of this. So first confirm that you have defined series for the chart.

Comment: Series Series1 = new Series();
            Chart1.Series.Add(Series1);
            Chart1.DataSource = myfavitems.AsEnumerable();
            Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Group Equipment Type";
            Chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Software"; Chart1.Databind(); At this position it brings that error.

Comment: i will get back to you as soon as possible. Your answer was the closest if that error doesnt pop up. I will add that code and get back to u in a few hours. Thanks

Comment: don't forget to mark it as an answer and rate this solution. so that it may help other user's as well.

Comment: Dont worry, I will :) I have to go through the solution that you provide and try integrate the concept with my working. And I need a break at the moment. So i will definitely get back to it. Thanks again :) I hope you can help me out if i have a question few hours down the track

Comment: Hi mate, I worked on the solution you provided. I have not binded it to a chart instead printed out the t.key and t.count using the system.diagnostics.debug.writeline and it prints 2 for boxer and 135 for vtec. Perfect. Now I am going to try and bind it to a chart. Can I still ask you question if i got any errors? I have also voted this answer up and accepted your answer. Thanks

Comment: the column that the car is type string. but contains 1's and 0's. The column engine_type is type string and contains vtec or boxers.

Answer (score 1):

The LINQ [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method is made for that :

```
var myitems = mylist.Where(item => item.Car_ == "1").GroupBy(item => item.Engine_Type);
```

will regroup every Engine_Type together.

If after that you do for example `myitems.ElementAt(0).Count()` you'll get how many duplicates of the first engine type you have.

Comment: Hi Pierre, i get this error "System.Linq.Lookup`2+Grouping[System.String,<>f__AnonymousType1`89[System.String,System.String," when i use that. I think i understand what you have done there but even then i get this answer

Comment: More precisely: this is the error. ArgumentException was unhandled by user code

Answer (score 0):

May be this will be useful for you please find the following link

[Find Duplicates using LINQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/08/19/find-duplicates-using-linq.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can use following linq:

```
var pl = from r in mylist
orderby r.Engine_Type    
group r by r.Engine_Type into grp
select new { key = grp.Key, cnt = grp.Count()};
```

In this way your pl collection will have all the engine types with respective counts.

Regards,

Nitin Joshi

Comment: Hi Nitin, according to your code, i am pulling all the instances of the engine types. There is no filter where i can separate people with cars and people without cars

Comment: But as per your code you have already filtered the collection on (a.Car_ == "1") so your mylist collection will only have the people with car.