# Unable to produce a chart using linq in csharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, visual-studio-2012, charts

I am coding in Microsoft Visual Studio 12 in ASP.net using c# and a noob at it.

This is what csv file looks like

```
ID, Engine Type, Car
111,vtec, 1
131,vtec, 1
157,boxer,1
148,boxer,1
167,vtec,1
158,,0
107,,0
```

ID should be a generic autonumber, Engine Type should be a type string and I don't know what Car should because it consists off 1's and 0's representing Boolean. This means that 1-customer has a car and 0 means that customer doesn't have a car.

This is how i create a list out of it.

```
var testingobject = (
    from line in File.ReadAllLines("testing.csv").Skip(0)
    let parts = line.Split(',')
    select new
    {
        ID = parts[0],
        Engine_Type = parts[1],
        Car = parts[2] //should i put int32.parse(parts[2]) here
    ).ToList();
```

I create a simple array which consists of ID,Engine Type,Car  convert it to a list using `ToList()` and then bind it to a dropdownlist, using this code:

```
string[] testingddl = new string[] { "ID", "Engine Type", "Car" };
List<String> mytestinglist = testingddl.ToList();
var mytestin = from m in mytestinglist
select m;
DropDownList1.DataSource = mytestin.AsEnumerable();
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

User selects Car and should give me the a chart that has engine type in x-axis and total on y-axis.

**The Problem**: The column consists of 1's and 0's meaning whether the customer has a car (1) or doesnt (0).
I would like to view how many users have different types of engines types and bind it to a, say a column chart. So the data should display on the x-axis, engine type and y-axis should have the total.  according to the data, there are 3 vtecs and 2 boxers. So vtecs represent a column with 3 total and boxers with 2.

I use this linq query and the following chart binding code.

```
if (tempval == "Car")// this is the current selected dropdown list value
{
    var myfavitems = testingobject.Where(a => a.Car == "1").ToList();
    foreach (var t in myfavitems.GroupBy(a => a.Engine_Type))
    {
        Series Series1 = new Series();
        Chart1.Series.Add(Series1);
        Chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(t.Key.ToString(), t.Count().ToString()).ToString();
        Chart1.DataSource = myfavitems.AsEnumerable();
        Chart1.Series[1].XValueMember = "Group Equipment Type";
        Chart1.Series[1].YValueMembers = "Software";
        Chart1.DataBind();
    // ...??
```

The error comes at the point where I am reading my columns from the csv files. The error says `Format exception was unhandled by user code: Input string was not in a correct format`

```
select new  
{
    ID = parts[0],
    Engine_Type = parts[1],
    Car = Int32.Parse(parts[2])
}
```

I dont know what is wrong with that statement. Could someone please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to have a class like this:

```
public class CarClass {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Engine { get; set; }
    public int Car { get; set; }
}
```

And then do something like:

```
var car_collection =
    from line in File.ReadAllLines("your_csv_name.csv").Skip(1)
    let parts = line.Split(',')
    select new CarClass()
    {
        Id = Int32.Parse(parts[0]),
        Engine = parts[1],
        Car = Int32.Parse(parts[2])
    };

var listy = car_collection.ToList();
```

Otherwise, notice the '{ }' and the '( )' , because yours don't match:

```
var car_collection =
    (from line in File.ReadAllLines("your_csv_name.csv").Skip(1)
    let parts = line.Split(',')
    select new CarClass()
    {
        Id = Int32.Parse(parts[0]),
        Engine = parts[1],
        Car = Int32.Parse(parts[2])
    }).ToList();
```

That should solve your problem with the error

Comment: You are a legend my friend. I set the class as you have done it and then I use the second set of code to pass the information into appropriate data type and convert to a list. The code runs perfectly if I dont include var listy = car_collection.ToList(); As soon as i include this statement the code gives me a format exception

Comment: a format exception?? weird ... worked for me ... can you paste the output ?

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll This is the output. And the error says Input string was not in a correct format and highlights "select new CarClass()"

Comment: might be your input. you using the same one you have in your code above?

Comment: Do you mean the table right at the top? Also i am only using the code up till "binding to a drop down list" in order to track what is actually going on with the code.

Comment: The csv file is stored here C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\testing.csv

Comment: Noctis!! It worked. There were two commas missing from the csv file for some odd reason.

Comment: :) ... well, I can be blamed for many things, but I can't be blamed for missing commas :)

Comment: haha. Now everything works except Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(t.key,t.count()); Key is a string whereas this statement requires two double values. So still not able to bind the chart

Comment: Obviously, Points.AddXY expects a point. you could parse the string to a double, and it should be able to handle the int ok ..

Comment: there is no option of parsing a string to double. t.key.parse isn't on the drop down list. Sorry, im slowly going up on the learning curve.

Comment: it cant be converted!! nevermind. Got to find another way to add the vtec and boxer to the x axis and the count accordingly to the y axis

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42086/discussion-between-noctis-and-manu)

Answer (score 0):

If your header row is in CSV file then

```
Car = Int32.Parse(parts[2])
```

is trying to parse `"Car"` to Int32.

Try reading file with:

```
File.ReadAllLines("testing.csv").Skip(1)
```

to skip header row.