# Bind chart using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, charts

I am coding in Visual studio 12 in asp.net using c#

I am having troubles binding a linq query to a chart. The linq query produces the correct output. But the code gives me a formatting exception.

This is the link to my code, could some please help me out. I don't know what is wrong and why wouldn't the data be displayed on the chart.

The linq contains all the information about the code.

[Unable to produce a chart using linq in csharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234111/unable-to-produce-a-chart-using-linq-in-csharp)

Comment: Please don't re-ask questions. If you need to, improve the original.

Comment: Hi Brad, I waited for a few hours for someone to help me out on that question and no one did so I had to ask this question. Anyways I'll keep in mind for next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#region ChartDataBinding
    //This method binds the chart to a given datasource.
    private void BindChart(object populations)
    {
        this.ChartWebControl1.Series.Clear();

        ChartSeries series = new ChartSeries("Populations");
        ChartDataBindModel dataSeriesModel = new ChartDataBindModel(populations);

        // If ChartDataBindModel.XName is empty or null, X value is index of point.
        dataSeriesModel.YNames = new string[] { "Population" };

        series.SeriesModel = dataSeriesModel;

        // ChartDataBindModel implements the IChartSeriesIndexedModel interface also.
        // series.SeriesIndexedModelImpl = dataModel;

        ChartDataBindAxisLabelModel dataLabelsModel = new ChartDataBindAxisLabelModel(populations);

        dataLabelsModel.LabelName = "City";

        ChartWebControl1.Series.Add(series);
        ChartWebControl1.PrimaryXAxis.LabelsImpl = dataLabelsModel;

        ChartWebControl1.PrimaryXAxis.TickLabelsDrawingMode = ChartAxisTickLabelDrawingMode.UserMode;
        ChartWebControl1.PrimaryXAxis.LabelIntersectAction = ChartLabelIntersectAction.MultipleRows;

        ChartWebControl1.PrimaryXAxis.Title = "City";
        ChartWebControl1.PrimaryYAxis.Title = "Population (Million)";
        SeriesStyles();
    }
    #endregion
```

Link:

http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/ui/chart/Data%20Binding/LINQDataSource/CS/linqdatasource.aspx

Comment: Where does it bind the data source? where do i addthe path of the csv file?

Comment: Manu you should open the provided link. To make it short the parameter "object populations" above is the point where you have to put your Linq Result.